# Visualize incomplete 2D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, mesh

How can i visualize 2D array with surface(`mesh`, `surf`) for incomplete dataset?

'Incomplete' means (`v` - known values, `0` - unknown):

```
    1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
1 | v | 0 | v | 0 | v
2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
3 | v | 0 | v | 0 | v
4 | v | 0 | v | 0 | v
5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Such data indexing is handy for analyzing non-linear relation between variables.

The thing i want is working somehow with `plot` function. Lets say, `x = [1,2,4,5]`. `plot` will show continuous figure.

Is it possible to do so for 2D arrays without manual interpolation? Don't care about smoothness. Linear connection of known points is alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have non-linear sampling (`x = [1 3 5]`, `y = [1 3 4]`), and you don't want to interpolate?  I don't think `surf` etc will handle it. Sounds like a job for `plot3`.

This is mildly ugly (see result) but I'm presuming you just want to visualise it to get a feel for the data.  First make up your `x` and `y` with `repmat` if you don't already have them like this:

```
x =

     1     3     5
     1     3     5
     1     3     5

y =

     1     1     1
     3     3     3
     4     4     4
```

Then you'll need your values without all the zeros in to match:

```
z =

     6     8    10
     6     5     4
     4     2     1
```

This can be plotted with markers (might be the simplest if you have lots of points).  Or you can use this trick to make a "mesh" out of two sets of lines:

```
plot3(x,y,z)
hold on
plot3(x',y',z')
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

Exactly as with your `plot` example, this simply linearly connects between the existing points.

[image]

Comment: As far as you can see, interpolating this kind of datasets is tricky enough. That's why i'm asking for embedded solution. And, as you mentioned, graph is mostly for 'look-and-go' use. Thank you for the solution, but still looking forward for better one (even if it's mythical) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `0` values for `NaN` values.
Both, `surf` and `mesh` work with `NaN`.

Comment: Sensible for the case where you have occasional zeros and don't want them to mess up your surface, but `NaN` values leave a blank, and don't connect between points.  See the difference between `plot([1,2,4,5])` and `plot([1,2,NaN,4,5])`. With the OP's example you'd end up with a blank `surf` because you don't have any sets of four adjacent points to define a patch.

Comment: exactly. shows nothing (not for example above, but for my actual dataset)